# How to speed up sqlite query?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this query:

```
String queryString =
    "SELECT column1 FROM table1 " +
    "WHERE column1 = ? OR column1 = ? ORDER BY column1";
sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(queryString, whereArgs);
```

I need to call `rawQuery` in `Recycleview` `Adapter` `getView()` method. Is it a way to speed it up? Do part of the initialization in adapter constructor? Cacheing the domain field somehow?

Comment: Show the database schema. Do you have any indexes?

Comment: I plan to add indexing, not yet exist.

Comment: You generally don't want to do database queries - or any heavy work, for that matter - in `Adapter` methods. Can you do it before you pass the dataset to the `Adapter`?

Comment: Populating a `GridView` and it is way not easy to do the query outside the Adapter. Query is done based on the position of the GridView element. Should I make an array of the 'record' and maintain this array when something changing?